# Is CTS necessary on a AES-CBC DRBG?

Tags: aes, cbc

As I understand it, CTS pads the last block and swaps it with the second last to compensate for a partial block of data. I have written a DRBG (Deterministic Random Bit Generator) using AES-CBC that only accepts an input size which falls on the block boundary.

Is CTS really necessary here? I can't imagine a way in which it's absence will affect the entropy of the output. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Could you show us the actual DRBG algorithm you've implemented? Normally CTS would not be required, but that depends on the actual algorithm.

Comment: The AES class, it's based on mono/bouncycastle with fixed params (256/128) and CBC done in-class. The generator that calls the class creates keys/IV and random start pos for monotonic integer arrays equal to 4Kib. The key/IV/Pos are stored in a key used to generate random data at either end for a Vernam cipher. It's large and complex, just let me know what you want me to post..

Comment: Tried to answer it without additional knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you don't want to reverse the encryption used within a DRBG. Schemes like PKCS#7 padding and CTS are required to deterministically reverse the *padding* during decryption. If you just want to have a final block, you should be fine by using zero padding until the end of the block.

Of course, if this zero padding is actually harming the output of your DRBG depends on the algorithm.

Comment: I guess my point was.. it doesn't need any padding, because final block is *always* a full block. So in this case, where padding is never required, would I even need CTS? I don't think so.. but just double-checking

Comment: For full blocks you don't need to do anything with regards to padding. I don't think CTS will have much influence on the quality of the output though, but in general I would not use it for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Thanks owlstead.. I did some more research and moved it to a counter(SIC) implementation..

Comment: Ah, that's more like it. CBC is not the best for this. Note that *just* using CTR is not enough; if you use CTR mode encryption on static valued blocks you can be *certain* that no blocks will be repeated. That means you can predict that certain values are *not* in the following blocks.

Comment: Laid out simply.. it is aes ctr encrypting arrays of ascending integers each started at a random position. 1024 * int32 to equal a block of 4096 bytes of random data, then a new key/iv/pos and so on to create a 'pad' file.. does this sound right?

Comment: No, not really. If the integers are really started at a random position, then you don't need this DRNG. Counters are predictable, so I'm afraid that you would still be able to predict that *another* value won't be in the stream.

Comment: On the other hand, the chances of it repeating are 1/2^128 for AES. However, AES has a relatively small output size compared to e.g. a hash function. For mall blocks of 2^14 bits it may be OK, but it would require careful consideration. You may want to post your scheme on SO, but beware - it's likely to be broken.

Comment: random as in RNGCryptoServiceProvider for integer pos, key is same but with entropy extractor (sha256).. If monotonic array is insufficient for seed data, then what would work?

Comment: Cannot say, not my level of expertise. I can only detect mistakes, I cannot prove a DRBG correct :)